# Orbeon: check if any yes-no answer in a repeated grid is true

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

I have a repeated grid with several controls, one of them being a yes-no control.

In a control outside the repeated grid I would like to display a warning (using a formula) that appears whenever any of the yes-no answers is yes.

My attempt:

```
contains(string-join($my-yes-no-control), 'true')
```

However, Orbeon Form Builder tells me that this is an `Incorrect XPath expression`. Seems like the string-join function is not available. Why not, and how could I do it otherwise?

Here is an example form:
http://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/1a97481f06e382fbfd689a4286a9ed3e1ef7c3be

Comment: Share source code and desired output

Comment: it's in the question... added an example link

Comment: What is your desired output? Do you want to get boolean `True` if radio-button `Yes` is selected or `False` if it's not?

Comment: if _any_ radio button is yes i want `true` else `false`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expression does it:

```
$my-yes-no-control/string() = 'true'
```

And you want to dig in deeper, there are in this expression maybe 2 things that aren't immediately obvious:

- The `/string()`: see this [detailed explanation](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/formulas/formulas-examples#testing-on-a-yes-no-answer-field) of why it is needed.
- In XPath, you can just compare a sequence to an item, and the comparison will return true if the item is present in the sequence.

Comment: Finally works, thanks! Took me some time to figure out that `=` is not the same as `eq`...
`The "value comparison" operators (eq, lt, etc.) are designed for comparing single values (i.e. sequences of one value each). The "general comparison" operators (=, <, etc.) are designed for comparing sequences of more than one value.`

Comment: Excellent Tagas, I'm glad it worked, and indeed, in this case `eq` behaves differently than `=`. -Alex